# encoding: unrtf SYMBOL.charmap needs to be altered

Tags: linux, character-encoding

I'm trying to convert some files from RTF to text. The originals were created with some Windows application (probably Word) but the conversion is taking place on a Linux server. The tool I wish to use is `unrtf` since it comes with my Linux distro (SLES !!.x) pre-installed... or at least I didn't have to intall it.

There isn't a lot of doco on `unrtf`. It works well and there is a man page with some limited info. My problem is that the encoding coming out is ISO-8859-1 and I need ISO-8859-15 in order to get a Euro symbol (€). What I'm getting is a not symbol (¬). Viewing the document in hex-mode I see that there is a value of xAC00 at the point where the symbol € should be.

Searching the web I found out that € has a unicde value of x20AC and ¬ has a unicode value of x00AC. A bit more searching suggested for an encoding of ISO-8859-15 the correct value would be x00A4. A lot of the information I found was contradictory and confusing (not to mention way off the topic which is `unrtf` after all).

Amongst the commands I've tried are:

```
unrtf --text $RTF > $XRTF 
unrtf --text $RTF | iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-15  > $XRTF
```

where $RTF and $XRTF are the input and output files respectively. I checked the supposed encoding of my rtf file with

```
file -bi $RTF
```

and this returned an answer of ISO-8859-1. So I tried the following:

```
unrtf --text $RTF | iconv -c -f ISO-8859-1 -t ISO-8859-15  > $XRTF
```

In one final grasp at straws I tried creating my own SYMBOL.charmap file and changed the value for the not symbol to "U<20AC>" which is the syntax for that file. Then I tried the command:

```
unrtf --text -P $HOME/usr/local/share/unrtf $RTF > $XRTF
```

All these attempts achieved absolutely nothing... except the second one which simply removed the not symbol altogether by virtue of the -c option (I think).

Anybody have any ideas on how I could achieve the desired conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a complete solution, but I do have an effective work-around. The first thing to note is that the encodings ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-15 are almost the same (see [this link](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-iso8859-15.html)). There are 8 differences. Secondly, how chars are displayed depends on the software reading the file and **not** on the conversion software (in this case `unrtf`).

Thus the task is reduced to just the one symbol (€ in place of ¬), since the others are not in use in the relevant files. This comes down to changing "xAC" to "xA4" in each file after the conversion. This can be done with a simple *sed* command:

```
sed 's/\xAC/\xA4/g' temp1.txt > temp2.txt
```

That's it. As I say: it's a work-around.

Changing the SYMBOL.charmap file should have worked, but then I'm no expert on `unrtf`, so maybe I just did it incorrectly.